# RFC 1228, правильные типы данных

Tags: lan, snmp, ethernet

Помогите разобраться. В RFC 1228 тип OiD определен как 0x03, в примерах OiD указан как 0х06. Какой вариант правильный? Также не понятно почему все OiDы начинаются с 0x2b, а не с 0х01 0х03? Может есть RFC, в котором более подробно описан SNMP-DPI?